# SQLAlchemy/Python 3 (default column value)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.4

I have an SQLAlchemy model that (simplified) looks like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

This worked fine with Python 2.7, but now that I've upgraded to Python 3.4.0 I get this error when trying to insert something into the database:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: utcnow() takes no arguments (1 given) (original cause: TypeError: utcnow() takes no arguments (1 given))
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`default` and `onupdate` functions can take an optional `context` argument. See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html?highlight=onupdate#context-sensitive-default-functions).  I'm not sure how sqlalchemy detects whether to pass this, but maybe something in 3.4 is messing with the detection.  You might want to [report a bug](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues).

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy has a known issue around this, as can be seen in [this section of the 0.9.4 release notes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_09.html#change-1c1ca7f7a0d5e6ba577a8a31920eba2d)